# Matrix multiplication involving a unitary matrix in exponential form and a simple matrix

Tags: matrices, mathematical-physics, unitary-matrices, hermitian-matrices

I am not sure if this is even a valid question, but it will help to clear my doubts anyway.
For context, check out [Violating the Thermodynamic Uncertainty Relation in the Three-Level Maser](https://arxiv.org/abs/2103.07791v2).

So I am given two (Hermitian) matrices -
$$H=\begin{pmatrix}
\omega_l & \epsilon e^{i\omega_dt} & 0\\
\epsilon e^{-i\omega_dt} & \omega_u & 0\\
0 & 0 & \omega_x
\end{pmatrix},$$
('$t$' is some parameter (time)) and,
$$X=\begin{pmatrix}
\omega_l & 0 & 0\\
0 & \omega_l+\omega_d & 0\\
0 & 0 & \omega_x
\end{pmatrix}.$$
With this Hermitian matrix $X$ we form a Unitary matrix: $e^{iXt}$.

Now my question is - how to find the new matrix: $H^{rot}=e^{iXt}He^{-iXt}?$
To be exact, I know how to find the matrix $XH$, but tell me how to find the other matrix $e^{iXt}H.$

Comment: $X$ is diagonal, so $\exp(iXt)$ would just be a diagonal matrix with entries $\exp(it\omega_l), \exp(it(\omega_l+\omega_d)), \exp(it\omega_x)$. Why do you need $XH$ by the way (and could you give the page number, please)?